# Validation in Railway.js on module object

Tags: railway.js

am new to Railway.js (one of those cases where someone else wrote this peace of software that I now need to update - great grr!)

I got a "Notification" model and want to add validation that if user don't provide a field from the UI I display a error like: "Message Required"

How do I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

refer to jugglingdb documentation. you need validator:

```
Notification.validatesPresenceOf('message')
```

Comment: Where do I place this? Also I got Notification defined in db/schema.js but if I place above in the modules/notification.js it can't find the "Notification" object.